# Illegal assignment from Integer to String at line 45 column 13

Tags: apex

```
logObj.MC_LineNumber__c = err.getLineNumber();
```

Why is it showing an error like "Illegal assignment from Integer to String" ?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that destination field type is same as that of the value you are trying to put into it.
If `MC_LineNumber__c` is of type string then use

```
logObj.MC_LineNumber__c = String.valueOf(err.getLineNumber());
```

Or else, specify return type of method `getLineNumber()` same as that of `MC_LineNumber__c`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
logObj.MC_LineNumber__c = String.valueOf(err.getLineNumber());
```

**EDIT** It might also help to consider changing `MC_LineNumber__c` to a Number field if it's only ever going to contain numbers.